# Most efficient way to numerically order an array from least to greatest?

Tags: arrays, performance, processing

I'm working with processing, and I was wondering what the best (most efficient) way of ordering an array was.  I basically want to be able to write a function that could take an array with, say, the ints 3,2,7,29,5,1 and order it like: 1,2,3,5,7,29.

I could figure out some inefficient way of doing, but i'm working with 100,000+ numbers and I don't know how to do this efficiently.

Sorry if this is a stupid question!

Comment: Processing has a sort function that will do this job for you, probably better than it could be written in user code. See [the API reference here](http://processing.org/reference/sort_.html). The code would look like this `float[] a = { 3,2,7,29,5,1 }; a = sort(a);`

Comment: It would be useful if you provide some extra info: which language are you using, what is the range of numbers to sort and is there any specific distribution of the numbers?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

int[] arr = new int[]{33,6,2,74,2,73,836,23};

void setup(){
  Arrays.sort(arr);
  println(arr);
}
```

Comment: this solution is plain Java code, making the normally compiler-agnostic Processing source code linked to needing Java, instead.

Comment: Yes, you’re right, but seems like user adm is using *normal* Processing. The Java-version is faster, than the Processing version and the question is about the **most efficient way**.

Comment: exactly: normal Processing consists of source code that exclusively uses the Processing API and programming model as detailed on processing.org, without java escaping or importing plain java archives (Processing libraries need to be specially compiled before you can import them in a pure Processing environment).

Answer (score 0):

Well... the most efficient way to sort an array just doesn't exist! There are 1000+ methods to sort an array, and the most efficient way depends on the distribution of data inside that array, and the programming language you are using.

My guess is to go with "quicksort".

Answer (score 0):

[Sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) in Wikipedia has a description of several ones. The performance of each algorithm is measured by its computational complexity.

You can search for implementations of these algorithms in several programming languages, depending on your input data or other considerations to your case of use.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sort()` function, which is part of the API for exactly this reason: http://processing.org/reference/sort_.html